# Constraint layout height 0dp is not working properly in mobile but showing correctly in previews when Jumio's dependecies added to the gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, gradle, android-constraintlayout

I tried to add KYC functionality to my project using the jumio third party sdk. but whenever I added the jumio dependecy to the constraint layout is not working properly. It showing the correctly in preview but not in the mobile application.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
//apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 61
        versionName "4.30"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
            // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
            enableSplit false
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
}



repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven { url 'https://mobile-sdk.jumio.com' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0") {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    // kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$rootProject.kotlin_version"

    // android support libraries
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    //JAXB
    implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2"

    // Jumio dependencies
    implementation "com.jumio.android:core:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jumio.android:linefinder:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jumio.android:mrz:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jumio.android:nfc:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jumio.android:barcode:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jumio.android:barcode-mlkit:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jumio.android:iproov:4.0.0"
    implementation "com.jumio.android:defaultui:4.0.0"
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Previous screen

screen before adding jumio sdk

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjCqR.png

Screen after adding jumio sdk

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xOH7.png

Answer (score 0):

Check your Base Activity Constraints. It is must to include following constraints :

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Add this Constraints,It will work like charm!!